# Finding repeat rate using sql

Tags: sql

I have a table mentioned below:
If X customers had made the purchase in the month of Jan, how many of them made them in Feb too i.e Y. (Repeat Rate: Y/X*100)

```
customer_no month
---------------------
1           jan
2           jan
3           jan
4           jan
11          jan
1           feb
2           feb
3           feb
9           feb
10          feb
```

Output:

```
 Repeat_Rate
 60%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would do it like:

```
   SELECT CAST(COUNT(yourtable_feb.customer_no) as FLOAT) 
          / CAST(COUNT(yourtable_jan.customer_no) AS FLOAT) AS Repeating_Rate
     FROM yourtable yourtable_jan
LEFT JOIN yourtable yourtable_feb
       ON yourtable_jan.customer_no = yourtable_feb.customer_no 
      AND yourtable_feb.mymonth = 'feb'
    WHERE yourtable_jan.mymonth = 'jan'
```

here a rextester, if you'd like to retest my query:
http://rextester.com/ESO11614

Comment: Could you please explain how it would work. It's little difficult to understand

Comment: just try it with following statement - you might understand the result better:
SELECT xyz_jan.*
      ,xyz_feb.*
  FROM xyz xyz_jan
left  JOIN xyz xyz_feb
   ON xyz_jan.customer_no = xyz_feb.customer_no 
  AND xyz_feb.mymonth = 'feb'
WHERE  xyz_jan.mymonth = 'jan'

Comment: the yourtable_jan includes all data with month january. then i do a left join to all records, which have mymonth = 'feb'. as customer_id 4 and 11 are not there for february (in your example: they don't have a purchase in february), there will be no yourtable_feb records for them - finally i just count all customer_no of february divided by amount of customer_no in january